# WordPress php redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added the code below to my functions.php file in wordpress but it's not working -- any tips?

```
if(is_page( 'company-registration' ))  
{
      wp_redirect('http://www.example.com', 301 ); exit;
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

By not working i mean that the redirect is not taking place.
I have also tried using the WP page id.

Comment: This is better asked at the [WordPress StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com). That said, what do you mean by "Not working"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The logic being used here is fine. Have you tried simply using the ID of the page instead?

Comment: Is anything is sent to the client prior to the wp_redirect header? What header do you get if you visit the company-registration page? You can check with http://web-sniffer.net/

Comment: Hi @Ohgodwhy, yes i have tried with the page id as well -- it's not redirecting at all or showing any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your snippet in a function hooked to [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect), OR put it at the very top of `page.php` (or any other page template), before the `get_header` call.

Comment: is the logic here correct: if(is_user_logged_in() && (is_page( '43' ))  )

      wp_redirect('http://domain.com', 301 ); exit;

Comment: logic is sound, check syntax: `if( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 43 ) ) { ... }`